# Setting values in aliased records

Tags: elm

I'm just starting out with Elm, so be nice:)

In the ["Random" example of the official Elm Guide](http://elm-lang.org/examples/random) the model seems to be initialized with the value 1 like this:

```
type alias Model =
  { dieFace : Int
  }


init : (Model, Cmd Msg)
init =
(Model 1, Cmd.none)
```

My understanding of this is that the code

```
Model 1
```

sets the value of the dieFace attribute in the record. Is this correct and if so: what is this strange syntax for setting the attribute of a record? I would have expected something  along the lines of

```
{ model | dieFace = 1 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Model` is a type alias for a record which has a single int value called `dieFace`.

There are a few ways to create a value of that type:

```elm
Model 1 -- treats Model as a function with a single parameter

{ dieFace = 1 } -- creates a record that happens to coincide with the Model alias
```

The strange syntax you see in `{ model | dieFace = 1 }` is short-hand for creating a new value based off an existing record value but changing one or more fields. It perhaps doesn't make much sense when your record type has a single field so let's create an arbitrary example:

```elm
type alias ColoredDie = { dieFace: Int, color: String }
```

You can play around in the [Elm REPL](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl#elm-repl) and perhaps this will help it make sense:

```elm
> blue3 = ColoredDie 3 "blue"
{ dieFace = 3, color = "blue" } : Repl.ColoredDie
> red3 = { blue3 | color = "red" }
{ dieFace = 3, color = "red" } : { dieFace : Int, color : String }
> red4 = { red3 | dieFace = 4 }
{ dieFace = 4, color = "red" } : { color : String, dieFace : number }
> green6 = { red4 | color = "green", dieFace = 6 }
{ dieFace = 6, color = "green" } : { color : String, dieFace : number }
```

You can [read up on Elm's record syntax here](http://elm-lang.org/docs/records).

Comment: Thanks Chad, best answer I got in a long time, and very fast.